# Finding text in a string then from a cell, then copying values over from the corresponding row to another cell

Tags: vba, excel

Here is what I want to happen:
In column A of Sheet2, each cell contains an email subject line. I want the macro to look through each cell and see if a cell from column D of Sheet1 is found somewhere within the subject line.

Then when this is found I want to copy over information from the row in Sheet1 corresponding to the cell from column D to column B in sheet 2 in the same row of the subject line the cell was found.

This is Sheet1 before the macro is run:

[image: Sheet1]

This is sheet2 before the macro is run:

[image: Sheet2]

Here is the code I have that does not work properly:

```
Sub Path()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Set rRng = Range("A2:A65000")

With Sheets(1).Activate
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rCell In rRng.Cells

            If InStr(1, rCell, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "E").Value, vbTextCompare) Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "B") = "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value & " - " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & "LOGGED" & "\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Value
            End If

        Next rCell
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

This is what happens after the macro has been ran:

[image: Sheet2 Result]

This is the outcome I want:

[image: Sheet2 wanted Result]

Comment: `MAIN_PATH` is not defined, and your concatentation string will always return the last line in your table on Sheet1, not the line where you found the match.

Comment: I have took 'MAIN_PATH' out. How would I change this?

Comment: Change the concatenation string so that it addresses the line where the match occurs, rather than the last line of the table, for each of the cell references.

Comment: Are you able to supply me with this answer as I am quite new to VBA..

Comment: just one comment on your code which surely cause it not working as you expect: you start using "i" to refer row number in sheet1, but later you also refer to row number in second sheet, you should use: `Sheets("Sheet2").cells(rCell.row,2)=...`

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers below for methods to choose the correct cell.  Then adapt them to your requirements.  Also, be sure you understand what is going on with the code so you will be able to develop and maintain code on your own in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should return the desired result:

```
Sub Path()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Set s1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop sheet 2
    For i = 1 To s2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Loop sheet 1
        For j = 1 To s1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            'If match found
            If Not InStr(1, s2.Cells(i, 1).Value, s1.Cells(j, 4).Value) = 0 Then
                s2.Cells(i, 2).Value = "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & s1.Cells(j, 2).Value & "\" & s1.Cells(j, 1).Value & " - " & s1.Cells(j, 3).Value & "\" & "LOGGED" & "\" & s1.Cells(j, 4).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at my edited post above. I have supplied an image of the outcome I would like to see

Comment: It seems you have set column A sheet 1 as the cells which are used to search within column A in sheet 2, rather than using Column D

Comment: I have put it through edit. It works perfectly now, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You were simply going to the last row of Sheet1 everytime, when filling the column "B" in Sheet2, in this line :

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "B") = _
    MAIN_PATH & "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Value & " - " & _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C65000").End(xlUp).Value & "\" & "LOGGED" & "\" & _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D65000").End(xlUp).Value
```

Try this :

```
Sub Path()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rCell.Row, "B") <> "FILLED" Then
                If InStr(1, rCell, .Cells(i, "E").Value, vbTextCompare) Then

                    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(rCell.Row, "B") = _
                        "1. Invoices+BUFs - " & _
                        .Cells(i, "B") & "\" & _
                        .Cells(i, "A") & " - " & _
                        .Cells(i, "C") & "\" & _
                        "LOGGED" & "\" & _
                        .Cells(i, "D")
                    Exit For

                End If
            Else
            End If

        Next i
    Next rCell

End With

Set rRng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If you look at my code in the original post, I have took out 'MAIN_PATH &' as this was not needed. I have also added in an image of the result I want to get. Your macro seems to paste the last found path into all cells in Sheet2 column B

Comment: Edit done! In fact the loops where in the bad order, the for each should be first like i changed it! And I'm not sure about your output as you didn't say much, but I added a test, if there is "FILLED" in Sheet2, B column, we won't write in it